# Google AMP - Redirect user after click on button by ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, amp-html

I want to redirect user after clicking a button by ajax response sent after clicking a button.
I tried with [amp-form](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-form/) but seems it does support ajax.

Flow is:

1. User clicks a button
2. Ajax request sent
3. Ajax response received with url to redirect and message
4. Message shown to user for 5 seconds, and after 5 seconds he is been redirected to the url.

This is simple to set in regular JS, but I didn't find how to achieve this with amp.

How can I redirect with amp after button click by the ajax response?

Comment: You could submit the form as usual, without ajax, and have the response page show the message and perform the redirect.

Comment: true, but i'm looking for a way to achieve this inside the same page